# Select element with specific character

Tags: r, text

I have a atomic vector with character with different length for each elements like belows:

```
 A <- c("ABCDE", "ADLBB", "ASDLB", "ABCDG", "ABCDGDL")
```

My task is to select those with "DL".

The tricky part is that DL is not always fixed to specific position of the elements.

My ideal answer is:

```
[1] "ADLBB" "ASDLB" "ABCDGDL"
```

I tried `grep("[DL]", A, value=TRUE)` but seems not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `grep` it would be

```
> A <- c("ABCDE", "ADLBB", "ASDLB", "ABCDG", "ABCDGDL")
> grep("DL", A, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
## [1] "ADLBB"   "ASDLB"   "ABCDGDL"
```

No need for the `[` to capture characters if you set `fixed = TRUE`.  It will capture "DL" as is.  Another variety is

```
> A[grep("DL", A, fixed = TRUE)]
## [1] "ADLBB"   "ASDLB"   "ABCDGDL"
```

---

**Since you mentioned you're learning regular expressions in R**, here are some other variations of `grep` that make it very handy in many situations.

Alone, it returns the indices of the captured regex

```
> grep("DL", A, fixed = TRUE)
## [1] 2 3 5
```

When we add `invert = TRUE`, we get the indices of the vector that did **not** match (essentially the opposite of the above line)

```
> grep("DL", A, fixed = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
## [1] 1 4
```

Adding `value = TRUE` to that, we get the values that did not match.  Again, the opposite.

```
> grep("DL", A, fixed = TRUE, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
## [1] "ABCDE" "ABCDG"
```

If we add some elements with lower case letters mixed in, we can capture those with `ignore.case`.  We also no longer want `fixed` because we're searching for variations in the cases.

```
> B <- c(A, "aBcdLe", "Dlabrt", "abcde")

> grep("DL", B, value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
## [1] "ADLBB"   "ASDLB"   "ABCDGDL" "aBcdLe"  "Dlabrt"
```

These arguments allow the user to cut down on lengthy regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too! As i can only accept one answer but i will check your answer too if it allow me to check both!

Comment: No worries at all.  Just glad I can help.  You should accept the best answer that works for you.  You could also wait for other answers to come in.  There may be a better one.  Also, the link that JT85 suggested is one of the best for learning regex in R. I use it a lot.

Comment: Hi @Richard, can i do sth like grep(c("AB", "DL"), A) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `grepl` for this:

```
A <- c("ABCDE", "ADLBB", "ASDLB", "ABCDG", "ABCDGDL")

grepl("DL", A)
```

output:

```
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

If you want to select only those observations:

```
A[grepl("DL", A)]
```

output:

```
#[1] "ADLBB"   "ASDLB"   "ABCDGDL"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works perfectly! Any good reference to learn natural language processing using R? Sometimes it is quite difficult to follow using help() in R.

Comment: Not that I know of, but certainly take a look at the `tm` package. If you google you can find a lot of material like: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing

Comment: Really thanks so much! I cant accept it as still within 10 mins XD